# How to create an xpath for random value selection from the drop down but I have to skip the selection placeholder value in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation, automation-testing

Currently, I am facing the issue of selecting a random value from the drop-down list, but I don't want to select the placeholder value in Selenium Java.
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl36R.png)
Can you please help me select a random value from the list, but I don't want to select placeholder value 0.
Thanks in advance.

I have tried with blow xpath, but sometimes it selects a placeholder value as well.
//*[@id='ddlEnquirySource']/div/ul/li

Comment: Please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Combine random number:

```
public static int getRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
    return (int) ((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
}
```

with `selectByIndex`:

```
WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.Id("ddlEnquirySource"));
List<WebElmenet> selectOptions = selectElement.findElements(By.TagName("option"));
Select mySelect = new Select(selectElement);
mySelect.selectByIndex(getRandomNumber(1, selectOptions.size()));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but the above code is not working.